# in R ggplot how to change labels for multiple barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to change the label of a multi-variable plot in ggplot
My first image is this:
[image]

The first image shows that I have two variables - Count and Total Gross
And I have x labels as G and N (which are the variable values I have in the data)
I want to change the x-labels to be more descriptive

how can I update my ggplot statement to introduce these new labels

```
 test %>%
   group_by(DiscInd) %>% 
   summarise(Count=n(),TotalGross=sum(Gross)/100000000) %>% 
   gather(Var, Val, -DiscInd) %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x=DiscInd, y = Val, fill=Var)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    xlab("Year vs Released Difference") + 
    ylab("Total Gross")                 +
    ggtitle("Total Movie with Gross ")
```

Is this possible?

Here are some records for my dataframe test

```
        DiscInd      Gross
          N        2783918982
          N        2207615668
          N        1670328025
          N        1519479547
          G        1514019071
          G        1404705868
```

UPDATED:
Also I am trying to change labels and formatting labels so that it does not overlap each other.

Comment: Make `DiscInd` a factor with the labels you want (in `aes`, if you don't want to change your data.frame), or set `breaks` and `labels` in `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: @alistare, scale_x_discrete was able to do the trick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say your new descriptive label names are *Label G Desc* and *Label N Desc* , is this what you want?

```
test %>%
  group_by(DiscInd) %>% 
  summarise(Count=n(),TotalGross=sum(Gross)/100000000) %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -DiscInd) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=DiscInd, y = Val, fill=Var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Label G Desc", "Label N Desc")) +
  xlab("Year vs Released Difference") + 
  ylab("Total Gross")                 +
  ggtitle("Total Movie with Gross ")
```

x-axis text with angle:

[image]

```
test %>%
  group_by(DiscInd) %>% 
  summarise(Count=n(),TotalGross=sum(Gross)/100000000) %>% 
  gather(Var, Val, -DiscInd) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x=DiscInd, y = Val, fill=Var)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Label G Desc", "Label N Desc")) +
  xlab("Year vs Released Difference") + 
  ylab("Total Gross")                 +
  ggtitle("Total Movie with Gross ")  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, size=15, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: how do we angle the Label, for long names, is there angle parm i can use